# Javascript - Incrementing specific numbers of a string

Tags: javascript, string, increment

I have a string that looks like this

```
    id = 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac';
```

Is there an easier way to increment the numbers at the end of "question1" and "answer0" inside of the string? I have tried to separate the contents of the string using the following method:

```js
id = 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac';

idArray = id.split('_');

originalArray = idArray.slice();

if (idArray) {
  idArray.pop();
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    idArray.shift();
  }
}
```

The above results in:

```js
idArray = ["question1","answer0"];
```

but the final result needs to be a string, I know I'll probably need to concatenate it later, so I can pass it into another argument. I just need to isolate those two numbers and increment only those two. I was searching for an easier way to finish that task but I haven't come across anything like that. Also jQuery isn't an option for me since I'm trying to accomplish this using just javascript and the console. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The posted content of `idArray = ["1","0"];` is not correct. The right result is `idArray = ["question1","answer0"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var id = 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac';
var incrementQuestion = function (id) {
 return id.replace(/question([0-9]+)/, function (val1, val2) {
     return "question" + (parseInt(val2) + 1)
 })   }

 var incrementAnswer = function (id) {
 return id.replace(/answer([0-9]+)/, function (val1, val2) {
     return "answer" + (parseInt(val2) + 1)
 }) }
```

then increment using:

```
id = incrementAnswer(id);
```

and

```
id = incrementQuestion(id);
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention the fact that I need independant control of the incrementation for each Question and Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the string "question1" and replace it with "question2" - or more accurately "question{any number here}" and replace with "question{any other number}"

```
var id = 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac'
var re = /question\d+/
var id2 = id.replace(re,"question2")
```

You can do the same for `answer\d+`

Answer (score 0):

You should use replace function of RegExp:

**Please run the example below:**

```js
var id = 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac';
alert('before:\r' + id)

id = id.replace(/question([0-9]+).*answer([0-9]+)/, function(a, b, c) {
  return 'question' + (parseInt(b) + 1) + '_answer' + (parseInt(c) + 1)
  //    Using parseInt to convert string to number
})

alert('after:\r' + id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a less verbose way of doing it:

```
var increment = function(_, prefix, n) { return prefix + (+n + 1) };
id.replace(/(question)(\d+)/, increment).replace(/(answer)(\d+)/, increment);
```

The parenthesized matches (i.e. the capturing groups) are passed as separate args to the replacement functions, and there you can just increment them and return with the corresponding prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateQA(question, answer) {
  return 'CourseContent1_activityContent34169_question1_answer0_ac'.replace(/^(.*question)(\d*)(_answer)(\d*)(.*)/gi, '$1' + question + '$3' + answer + '$5');
}
```